# nuget adding unnecessary references to my project

Tags: visual-studio, nuget

I've recently installed nuget for a VS project I am working on. However, now that I created a second, completely unrelated project, nuget is adding references to my local packages, making it so that I can't share my project. Specifically, it adds the following line to my project.lock.json

```
"packageFolders": {
     "C:\\<mylocalpath>.nuget\\packages\\": {}
 }
```

Perhaps I don't understand how nuget works yet, but the weird part is that I don't have a reference to any nuget packages in this folder so I don't know why it gets added; this is a very simple project from a VS C# template. I would like to know how to prevent/fix this behavior other than physically removing those lines every time I build the project.

Thank you

Comment: Which project template do you use? How do you share your project and what exception do you get?

Comment: Hi, I share the project in the crudest way possible: copying and pasting the solution's folder. I know this isn't the best way, but for sharing small sample projects and such it is not worth setting up git.

The exception is that it can't find the file C:\\<mylocalpath>.nuget\\packages\\" Of course I don't get the exception, but whomever I sent the project to does.

Answer (score 0):

The project.lock.json file is generated in the process of restoring the NuGet packages in projects that use project.json. [See here](https://docs.nuget.org/ndocs/schema/project.json) for more info. Therefore, the "packageFolder" in project.lock.json will not affect you to share your project.

Some project template has default nuget package installed, such as UWP app, it installed "Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform" package by default. This is why when we create this type of project, it will add "packageFolder" into project.lock.json file. So please check your project template first.